# how to enumerate class method then chain them with itertools.product() in python?

Tags: python, enumeration, method-chaining, class-method

I just learned yesterday from this site that I can:

```
class Seq(object):
    def __init__(self, seq):
        self.seq = seq
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.seq)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.seq)
    def all(self):
        return Seq(self.seq[:])
    def head(self, count):
        return Seq(self.seq[:count])
    def tail(self, count):
        return Seq(self.seq[-count:])
    def odd(self):
        return Seq(self.seq[1::2])
    def even(self):
        return Seq(self.seq[::2])
    def reverse(self):
        return Seq(self.seq[::-1])

>>> s = Seq(range(0, 100))
>>> print s.head(10).odd().even().reverse()
[9, 5, 1]
```

I want to enumerate possible combination of those sequence method chains inside of class Seq, may sort of:

```
itertools.product([s.head,s.odd,s.even,s.reverse], repeat=4)    
# may not just limited those 4 functions
```

1. how to use the `itertools.product()` to

   1). generate invoke-able function chains list? just like this:

   `foo = s.head().odd().even().reverse()`

   2). generate eval()able chain strings then I can store in ascii file or eval() later or for logging purpose?
2. the `head()`, `tail()` may accept parameter, and `even()`, `odd()` is not need to, for example,
   the paremeter of head() and tail() may from lists:

   ```
     head_lmt = [10,20,30]
     tail_lmt = [30,40,50]
     foo = s.head().odd().tail().reverse()
                  ^------------------------------------head_lmt  10 or 20 or 30
                               ^-----------------------tail_lmt  30 or 40 or 50
   ```

If my Q1 is possible, how I can fill those parameter into the invoke-able list and the eval()-able string, a.k.a generate more specific invoke-able list and the eval()-able string?

Thanks!

Comment: you could do `class Seq(list)`, drop `__init__, __repr_, __str__` and use only `self` instead of `self.seq`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that something like "s.head()" means a method which is "bound" to that specific instance of Seq, that is, "s." Something like "Seq.head()" means a method which is unbound, so one can still pass in different instances of Seq.

From there it simply requires basic functional composition and string concatenation.

```
def chain_method(from_method, to_method):
    def inner(arg):
        return to_method(from_method(arg))
    return inner

possible_funcs = []
log_strings = []
for possible_combo in itertools.product([Seq.head,Seq.odd,Seq.even,Seq.reverse], repeat=4):
    meta_method = possible_combo[0]
    for method in possible_combo[1:]:
        meta_method = chain_method(meta_method, method)
    log_string = []
    for method in possible_combo:
        log_string.extend(['.', method.__name__, '()'])
    possible_funcs.append(meta_method)
    log_strings.append("".join(log_string))
```

I'm not sure what you mean by the examples for the additional parameters, though. How do you intend to combine the different parameter values with the different combinations of functions?